# Set Regolith status to the top of the screen

Tags: i3, regolith

I am using Regolith 2 on Ubuntu 22.04. I would like to move the status bar to the top of the screen (like in i3). This version of Regolith now uses the concept of [partials](https://regolith-desktop.com/docs/using-regolith/configuration/#i3-features) for configuration, but none of those seem to offer a means of toggling the status bar.

The only place where something resembling this setting appears is in the file `/usr/share/regolith-look/default/i3-wm`. However modifying that file has no effect on the status bar.

How can I move the status to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this setting is not configurable with partials, but rather in the  `Xresources` file:

```
echo "i3-wm.bar.position:   top" >> ~/.config/regolith2/Xresources
```

From [issue #81](https://github.com/regolith-linux/regolith-desktop/issues/81#issuecomment-1474947129) at GitHub.